# Extract Z-values from multipoint data

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, z-value

I'm using ArcMap/ArcScene 10.4.1

I am trying to extract z-values out of the file in the picture below, but can't find any way to do it. The height is different for the points, so it has z-values, but how do I extract them?

[image]

Comment: Extracting **just** the Z values seems pointless.  There are many ways to extract the X,Y,Z triplets, and most of them involve a few lines of Python, to extract the vertices from the geometry column.

Answer (score 1):

If you are wanting to extract the Z value from the PointZ geometry and add it back to the dataset as a field which you could then use in some other application then you can use the [Add Geometry Attributes tool](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/data-management-toolbox/add-geometry-attributes.htm) setting the parameter geometry properties to POINT_X_Y_Z_M.

You can also use the [Add Z Information tool](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/3d-analyst/add-z-information.htm).

Comment: Add Geometry Attributes did not work, I did not get the option to add POINT_X_Y_Z_M, since it was a multipoint. My solution was to convert the multipoint to point with ET Geowizards.

Comment: You could have used the multi-part to single part tool (available at all license levels), no need for using third party software, but either way sounds like you have resolved it.